# Change Domain on Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use the following code, the code tries to redirect me to

http://www.abccom.com/www.yahoo.com  where abccom is my current domain.  How do I get this code to completely take me out of the abccom.com domain?

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
    <script runat="server" language="C#">
     void Page_Load()
   {
    // Response.RedirectPermanent("http://yahoo.com");
    Response.Redirect("http://yahoo.com");
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: Sounds weird I just tested it and it works... Try to delete browser cache maybe something got stuck there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  That is the solution.  Clearing the cache.  Thanks!